# Using with-editor and custom key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, magit

I am trying to use the [with-editor](https://github.com/magit/with-editor) package with the `kubectl edit` command in the [kubernetes-el](https://github.com/kubernetes-el/kubernetes-el) package. I proposed a [patch](https://github.com/kubernetes-el/kubernetes-el/pull/186/files) for the same.

I am trying to understand how to create custom key bindings like `C-c C-k` similar to the one associated with the Magit commit buffer.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please focus your question, which seems to be about how to create a key binding in a particular context. Maybe show a recipe of what you've tried. Don't just link to other pages to define your question - say whatever is relevant in the question itself.